# Attribute table empty with custom driver in newer versions

Tags: attribute-table, ogrinfo

I've written a custom ogr driver for one of our own formats.
When loading the data I get to see vector data nicely displayed in Brighton/Essen/Pisa. However, when opening the 'Attribute Table' only
Brighton is capable of showing the data. Using Identify on a feature I do get it's correct attributes in all 3 versions. All 3 versions also display the correct amount of features.

The attribute table shows 0 Features in Essen and Pisa.
On the other hand if i load a shp, and check the contents of the Attribute table
I do get to see all the attributes in all 3 versions.

This leads me to believe that somehow the attribute table does not get updated upon new feature request to the driver (or something of the sort). The Driver is an RTree implementation and will not return features unless they are inside the provided boundingbox / Envelope.

Any hints?

p.s using ogrinfo i'm also seeing al the correct attributes just like with identify.